# How many ways are there to factor a number so that the factors are relatively prime?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, prime-factorization

Sorry while preping for finals I stumbled upon this problem.
Does the answer involve using Euler's Totient Function?

> Integers a and b are relatively prime if gcd(a,b) = 1. 
>   How many ways can we factor 88,200 so that the factors are rela-tively prime?

Comment: Yes, you want to use Euler's totient function.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_totient_function

Comment: By factor, do you mean write $88200=ab$ where $\gcd(a,b)=1$?

Comment: I'm not sure what it's asking :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$N = 88200 = 2^3 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 5^2 \cdot 7^2$.  So any way we write $N = ab$ with $\gcd(a,b) = 1$, we build $a$ and $b$ from disjoint prime sets from $\{2,3,5,7\}$. There are $2^4$ ways to pick the primes for $a$ (and then we include the full power of that prime, as $b$ cannot have it as a divisor) and then $b$ is determined uniquely. So 16 different ways, as $N$ has 4 distinct prime divisors. This includes $1\cdot N$, which you might want to rule out. I that case, there are 14 ways left. If order does not matter we overcount by 2, so for $k$ prime factors we are left with $2^{k-1} -1$, if we discount the ones with a 1.

If order does not matter and we consider any number of factors, unequal to 1: we again look at the number of ways we can partition the set of primes:

$\{2\}, \{3\}, \{5\}, \{7\}$ is one, $\{2,3\}, \{5,7\}$ another. Just enumerate those and take their powers to get all those factorisations. In general we thus need the [Bell number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number) of $n$ if we have $n$ many prime factors. This counts the number of partitiions of a set of $n$ members into non-empty subsets.

This disregards sign (just positive numbers and no 1's).

Comment: Would you not be double counting some cases? (e.g. with $a = 2^3$ and $b = 3^2 \cdot 5^2 \cdot 7^2$ and $a = 3^2 \cdot 5^2 \cdot 7^2$ and $b = 2^3$ being counted as two factorizations).

Comment: @user2825632 indeed, divide by 2.

Comment: Two more points: I think $1 \cdot N$ is a factorization, so we should still count it. Also, I don't think the problem specified that we need only two factors - we may have more factors (since it seems representing it as a product of four factors with $88200 = 8 \cdot 9 \cdot 25 \cdot 49$ should also be considered a factorization).

Comment: @user2825632 We have to discount $1$ as a factor or we can always add 1's and get "new" factorisations.

Comment: Right, but we can just say $88200 = 88200$ is the factorization, right?

Comment: @Henno Brandsma What do you mean by "and then b is determined uniquely"? Also, it appears to be a and b can also be negative integers, so I should double the final result?

Comment: @soyfroggy If $N = ab$ and we choose $a$ then $b = N/a$, so uniquely determine. If negative we add $-$ to both to double the number, yes.

Answer (score 0):

For this preoblem you need only consider the prime *divisors* of $n$, i.e., without their exponent. If $n$ is divisible by $k$ different primes, then we can pick any subset of this $k$-set and multiply the powers of these primes together to obtain $a$ and similarly obtain $b$ from the rest. As there are $2^k$ subsets of a $k$-element set, ...

Note that if $a,b$ are only required to be *integers* as opposed to *positive integers*, the number of solutions doubles.

Answer (score 0):

We interpret the question as asking for the number of *unordered pairs* of (distinct) divisors of $n$ that are relatively prime. For me it is easier to think in terms of ordered pairs.

So we are producing an ordered pair $(x,y)$ of relatively prime divisors of $n$. Examine one after the other the primes $p_i$. At each prime we have three types of choices: (i) assign $p_i$ to $x$; (ii) assign it to $y$; (iii) assign it to neither. If we  assign $p_i$ to $x$, it can be done in $a_i$ ways, for the *power* of $p_i$ is at our disposal.  Same with $y$. And we can assign to neither in $1$ way,for a total of $2a_i+1$. Thus the total number of ordered pairs is $P$, where
$$P=\prod_1^k(2a_i+1).$$
This includes the ordered pair $(1,1)$. Now for unordered pairs of distinct relatively prime divisors, there are $\frac{P-1}{2}$ possibilities.  Hope you can take it from here.

Comment: Sorry but could you please explain or link to Wikipedia what that notation is? Is this like a summation notation?

Comment: Oh, no, no that is the product notation

Comment: Got it. So am I using it correctly: P = (2(1)+1)*(2(2)+1)*(2(3)+1)*(2(4)+1)

Comment: Yes, it is correct.